# Some Blocks of Code gets stuck in a loop, I do not know why

Tags: arduino-uno, loop

[image]

The code below Gets stuck at function "Led Off?" & "Check button".
I'm using Blockyduino editor.
The check button code was intended as a toggle switch for the lights. When I deleted "Led Off?" and "Turn off All LED", the code did not get stuck.

```
int Button_Status;

// Toggle Code for the button.
void Check_Button() {
  Serial.println("Check button Activated");
  if (Button_Status == 1) {
    if (digitalRead(13)) {
      Button_Status = 0;
    }
  }
  if (Button_Status == 0) {
    if (digitalRead(13)) {
      Button_Status = 1;
    }
  }
  LED_OFF_();
}

void Left_Animation() {
  Check_Button();
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  Check_Button();
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
  Check_Button();
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  Check_Button();
  delay(300);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
  Serial.println("Finshed Left cycle");
}

void Right_Animation() {
  Check_Button();
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  Check_Button();
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
  Check_Button();
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  Check_Button();
  delay(300);
  digitalWrite(10, LOW);
  digitalWrite(11, LOW);
  Serial.println("Finished Right cycle");
}

// Main Loop Core
void Main_Loop() {
  while (Button_Status == 1) {
    Left_Animation();
    Right_Animation();
    Serial.println("Finshed Main Loop 1111");
  }
  while (Button_Status == 0) {
    Check_Button();
    Serial.println("Finished Main Loop 2222");
  }
}

// Checks if button toggle variable is off.
void LED_OFF_() {
  Serial.println("LED off? Activated");
  if (Button_Status == 0) {
    Turn_Off_All_LED();
  }
  Main_Loop();
}

// Turns off all LED
void Turn_Off_All_LED() {
  Serial.println("LED Turn off Activated");
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(6, LOW);
  digitalWrite(7, LOW);
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  digitalWrite(10, LOW);
  digitalWrite(11, LOW);
  Main_Loop();
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, INPUT);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  // Start
  Button_Status = 1;
  Main_Loop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with infinite recursion in this program: `loop()`
calls `Main_Loop()`, which calls `Left_Animation()`, which calls
`Check_Button()`, which calls `LED_OFF_()`, which calls `Main_Loop()`,
which calls `Left_Animation()`, which calls `Check_Button()`, which
calls `LED_OFF_()`, which calls `Main_Loop()`, which calls... This will
pretty quickly exhaust the memory of your Arduino.

If you only know about graphical programming, this may not make too much
sense to you. So I ask you to imagine that, in your definition of
`Main_Loop()` (the big structure titled “to Main Loop”) you replace the
smallish box labeled “Left Animation” by its own definition (the big
structure labeled “to Left Animation”). Within this definition, you
replace “Check Button” by its own definition and so on. You will soon
reach a point where you need to embed the definition of `Main_Loop()`
within itself. It should then look more or less like this:

```
Main Loop
│ repeat while Button Status = 1
│ do Left animation
│ │  │ Check Button
│ │  │ │ Serial Print “Check button Activated”
│ │  │ │ ...
│ │  │ │ LED OFF?
│ │  │ │ │ Serial Print “LED off? activated”
│ │  │ │ │ if Button Status = 0
│ │  │ │ │ do Turn Off All LED
│ │  │ │ │ Main Loop
│ │  │ │ │ │ repeat while Button Status = 1
│ │  │ │ │ │ do Left animation
│ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ Check Button
│ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ Serial Print “Check button Activated”
│ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ ...
│ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ LED OFF?
│ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ │ Serial Print “LED off? activated”
│ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ │ if Button Status = 0
│ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ │ do Turn Off All LED
│ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ │ Main Loop
│ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ │ │ repeat while Button Status = 1
│ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ │ │ do Left animation
│ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ Check Button
│ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ Serial Print “Check button Activated”
│ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ ...
│ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ LED OFF?
│ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ │ Serial Print “LED off? activated”
│ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ │ if Button Status = 0
│ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ │ do Turn Off All LED
│ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ │ │ │  │ │ │ Main Loop
...etc ad infinitum...
```

Note that it is possible to write programs using [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)), but:

1. This is kind of an “advanced topic”, not suitable for someone still
   programming at a graphic level.
2. You have to take precautions in order to avoid the program to
   infinitely recurse.
3. On a microcontroller with little memory, you have to make sure the
   recursion is always very shallow. Which is hard, so people writing
   embedded code tend to avoid recursion altogether.